# How could I make my docker container connect to a proxy?

Tags: proxy, docker

I am running docker 19.03 on Ubuntu 16.04. There is a V2ray client being built these days.

Now I have problems on how to make my container connect to that proxy. I have read some questions on StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827496/how-to-configure-docker-container-proxy) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078248/how-can-i-make-all-my-docker-containers-use-my-proxy). And I have also read official documents on [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/). Those help me a lot but not enough.
Now my questions are following:

1. Those documents mentioned to configure the Docker client. Like modify `~/.docker/config.json` file. This is a once and for all method. But it will effect on the containers those are created after I modified the file and restarted docker. I have some other containers running now and I just want only this container to connect to the proxy because the proxy is unstable and I don't want the proxy to affect the work of other containers. So this scheme cannot be used.
2. Those documents also mentioned that we can set environment variables to make a container connect to a proxy. For example, when using command `docker run`, we can add `-env HTTP_PROXY="http://localhost：1080/"` to force the container to connect to the proxy. But there be only two examples on command `docker run` and `Dockerfile`. I used `docker-compose` to build my container. I have added `environment` item to my docker-compose file, but it doesn't work. So I have no idea about how to do that when using `docker-compose`.

My `docker-compose.yml` file is following:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  openethereum:
    image: openethereum/openethereum
    container_name: openethereum
    volumes:
      - /mnt/pgdata/ETH:/home/openethereum/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum
    command: --tracing=off --warp-barrier=12088645
    environment:
      HTTP_PROXY: http://172.21.0.1:2080/
      HTTPS_PROXY: https://172.21.0.1:2080/
```

I use `172.21.0.1` as the ip address of my container to connect to the proxy because I know that the ip adress of this container is `172.21.0.2` and my proxy is listening to all ip addresses. I'm not sure if this is the correct usage, and if there are any problems, thank you for pointing it out.

I installed `proxychains` on the computer and configured it. When I run command `proxychains curl www.google.com`, I got a lot of HTML text. But after I
go inside my container by running command `docker exec -it openethereum sh`, I run command `curl www.google.com` again. After that I waited for a long time, and finally it told me that the address could not be resolved.

Thank you very much for reading my question, if you have any solutions, and thank you for sharing your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if I understand correctly, you want to set the proxy in your docker container, but cannot since the proxy doesn't have a stable address.

I don't believe you can change the proxy in a running docker container, without having some kind of hook in every process.

I think your best bet would be some kind of intermediate that would have a stable address, that could be reconfigured on demand as the upstream proxy changes.

Alternatively, if you run your containers in some kind of cradle, it might be possible to have them fast fail, and pick up new proxy details on restart.

Comment: You may not understand what i said. The container I mentioned is not actually running. I can run a new container freely, but all the solutions I know about setting up a proxy for a container require restarting the docker service. So the solution I hope to get is to let all network connections of a certain container pass through a certain HTTP proxy, which is deployed on the host and listens to a certain port of the host.

Comment: Hmmm - ok; so what I'm hearing is that you want to be able to start a new docker container with a specific proxy container configuration. You're trying to pass this as environment config, but for some reason it's not working. In this case, when a container is running, I'd suggest `docker exec -ti container_name_or_id sh`'ing into it, and running `env | grep -i proxy`. Also if possible try to retrieve something with curl or wget. If this works, then perhaps your app inside your docker container needs the proxy set in a certain way. Please lmk how you get on so I can usefully update my answer.

Comment: I said in the question. I ran the command `docker exec -it openethereum sh` and went into my container. Then I ran the command `curl www.google.com`, but it turned out that the address could not be resolved. At the same time, I also explained that it can access google by connecting to my agent on the host and running the same command. So by comparison, I think my proxy configuration is fine, but the docker configuration doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried to run the command you mentioned in the container. In fact, it can indeed display the configured `HTTP_PROXY` item. However, it is still not available to directly use `curl` to access Google.